# Javascript display problems with dynamic dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dynamic

experts! I have some problems with two dynamic dropdown menus. Here is my fiddle:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/User001/jwajc/32/)

Here is my jQuery and Javascript:

```
var num_rows = 1;
var num_tests = 1;
var myArray = new Array();

function firstSelection(id) {
    var index = id.replace( /\D+/g, '');
    var item = $("#select" + index + "").val();
    var object = item.replace(/\d/g, "");

    var table = $("#test");

    if(object == 'analize') {
        table.find('tr').each(function(i) {
            $("#selectTest" + i + "").empty();
            $("#selectTest" + i + "").append("<option value=''/><option value='analizetest1'>AnalizeTest1</option><option value='analizetest2'>AnalizeTest2</option><option value='analizetest3'>AnalizeTest3</option>");
        });
    }
    else if(object == 'create') {
        table.find('tr').each(function(i) {
            $("#selectTest" + i + "").empty();
            $("#selectTest" + i + "").append("<option value=''/><option value='createtest1'>CreateTest1</option><option value='createtest2'>CreateTest2</option>");
        });
    }
    else if(object == 'draft') {
        table.find('tr').each(function(i) {
            $("#selectTest" + i + "").empty();
            $("#selectTest" + i + "").append("<option value=''/><option value='drafttest1'>DraftTest1</option><option value='drafttest2'>DraftTest2</option><option value='drafttest3'>DraftTest3</option>");
        });
    }
    else {
        table.find('tr').each(function(i) {
            $("#selectTest" + i + "").empty();
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addObjekt").click(function() {
        num_rows = $("#objectTable tr").length;

        $("#objectTable").append("<tr id='objectRow" + num_rows + "'><td><input class='text' type='text' id='pbz" + num_rows + "' name='pbz" + num_rows + "' value='" + num_rows + "' readonly/></td><td><select id='select" + num_rows + "'><option/><option value='analize" + num_rows + "'>Analize</option><option value='create" + num_rows + "'>Create</option><option value='draft" + num_rows + "'>Draft</option></select></td><td><button type='button' id='selectButton" + num_rows + "' onclick='firstSelection(id);'>Select</button></td><td><button type='button' id='copy" + num_rows + "'>Copy</button></td></tr>");  
    });

    $("#deleteObjekt").click(function() {
        var row = $("#objectTable tr").length - 1;

        if(row > 1) {
            $("#objectRow" + row + "").remove();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
        }
    });

    $("#addTest").click(function() {
        num_tests = $("#test tr").length;

        $("#test").append("<tr id='testRow" + num_tests + "'><td><input class='text' type='text' id='zaehler" + num_tests + "' name='zaehler" + num_tests + "' value='" + num_rows + "-" + num_tests + "' readonly/></td><td><select id='selectTest" + num_tests + "'></select></td><td><button type='button' id='parameter" + num_tests + "'>Parameter</button></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
    });

    $("#deleteTest").click(function() {
        var test_row = $("#test tr").length - 1;

        if(test_row > 1) {
            $("#testRow" + test_row + "").remove();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
});

function showMatrix() {
    num_rows = $("#objectTable tr").length - 1;
    num_tests = $("#test tr").length;

    for(var x = 0; x < num_rows; x++) {
        myArray[x] = new Array();
        myArray[x] = $("#select" + (x + 1) + "").val();

        for(var z = 0; z < num_tests; z++) {
            myArray[x][z] = firstSelection.item + firstSelection.index;
        }

    }

    alert(myArray);
}
```

The problems are:

1. The second dropdown list doesn't get populated based on the selection of the first one yet. For some reason it is not working properly in the fiddle, it is running fine in the environment I use.
2. How can I change the code, so that I see the second dropdown populated also for the new rows added later, not only for the already existing ones?
3. Last, I want the rows on the right side to be "attached" only to the single object they are linked to on the left side. Which means that selecting an object on the left side should only display its respective tests. I am not fluent in Javascript, I started with the idea of creating a two-dimensional array, but got stuck.

I know this might be a bit too much to ask, but I would deeply appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: where is firstSelection defined???...  myArray[x][z] = firstSelection.item + firstSelection.index;

Comment: It was supposed to be an outer reference to parameters in the firstSelection function.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the function `firstSelection` is in the scope. Move that function inside

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //...
});;
```

It will work if your code is correct.

I suggest this because I got the following error while running your code:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: firstSelection is not defined
```

Ok Try this. It is working. Before that edit the HTML and JS like the following:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="panel" class="panel">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="objectTable" class="objectTable">
                    <tr id="initial">
                        <td width="20px">Number</td>
                        <td>Object</td>
                        <td align="right"><button type="button" id="addObjekt" href="#">+</button><button type="button" id="deleteObjekt" href="#">-</button></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="objectRow1">
                        <td><input class="text" type="text" id="pbz1" name="pbz1" value="1" readonly/></td>
                        <td><select id="select1">
                            <option/>
                            <option value="analize1">Analize</option>
                            <option value="create1">Create</option>
                            <option value="draft1">Draft</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td><button type="button" id="selectButton1">Select</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" id="copy1">Copy</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table id="test" class="test">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Subnumber</td>
                        <td>Test <button type="button" id="addTest" href="#">+</button><button type="button" id="deleteTest" href="#">-</button></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="testRow1">
                        <td><input class="text" type="text" id="zaehler1" name="zaehler1" value="1-1" readonly/></td>
                        <td><select id="selectTest1">
                        </select></td>
                        <td><button type="button" id="parameter1">Parameter</button></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**JS:**

```
var num_rows = 1;
var num_tests = 1;
var myArray = new Array();
var globalIndex = 0;
var globalObject = '';

$(document).ready(function() {     

    $('#selectButton1').click(function(){
       firstSelection(this.id);
    });

    function firstSelection(id) {
    var index = id.replace( /\D+/g, '');
    var item = $("#select" + index + "").val();
    var object = item.replace(/\d/g, "");
    globalIndex = index;
    globalObject = object;
    var vars = {index: index, item: item};

    //var table = $("#test");

    document.getElementById("zaehler1").value = index + '-1';

    if(object == 'analize') {
        $("#selectTest1").empty();
        $("#selectTest1").append("<option value=''/><option value='analizetest1'>AnalizeTest1</option><option value='analizetest2'>AnalizeTest2</option><option value='analizetest3'>AnalizeTest3</option>");
    }
    else if(object == 'create') {
        $("#selectTest1").empty();
        $("#selectTest1").append("<option value=''/><option value='createtest1'>CreateTest1</option><option value='createtest2'>CreateTest2</option>");
    }
    else if(object == 'draft') {
        $("#selectTest1").empty();
        $("#selectTest1").append("<option value=''/><option value='drafttest1'>DraftTest1</option><option value='drafttest2'>DraftTest2</option><option value='drafttest3'>DraftTest3</option>");
    }
    else {
        $("#selectTest1").empty();
    }

    return vars;
}

    $("#addObjekt").click(function() {
        num_rows = $("#objectTable tr").length;

        $("#objectTable").append("<tr id='objectRow" + num_rows + "'><td><input class='text' type='text' id='pbz" + num_rows + "' name='pbz" + num_rows + "' value='" + num_rows + "' readonly/></td><td><select id='select" + num_rows + "'><option/><option value='analize" + num_rows + "'>Analize</option><option value='create" + num_rows + "'>Create</option><option value='draft" + num_rows + "'>Draft</option></select></td><td><button type='button' id='selectButton" + num_rows + "' onclick='firstSelection(id);'>Select</button></td><td><button type='button' id='copy" + num_rows + "'>Copy</button></td></tr>");  
    });

    $("#deleteObjekt").click(function() {
        var row = $("#objectTable tr").length - 1;

        if(row > 1) {
            $("#objectRow" + row + "").remove();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
        }
    });

    $("#addTest").click(function() {
        num_tests = $("#test tr").length;

        $("#test").append("<tr id='testRow" + num_tests + "'><td><input class='text' type='text' id='zaehler" + num_tests + "' name='zaehler" + num_tests + "' value='" + globalIndex + "-" + num_tests + "' readonly/></td><td><select id='selectTest" + num_tests + "'></select></td><td><button type='button' id='parameter" + num_tests + "'>Parameter</button></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");

        $("#test").find('tr').each(function(i) {
            if(globalObject == 'analize') {
                $("#selectTest" + i + "").append("<option value=''/><option value='analizetest1'>AnalizeTest1</option><option value='analizetest2'>AnalizeTest2</option><option value='analizetest3'>AnalizeTest3</option>");
            }
            else if(globalObject == 'create') {
                $("#selectTest" + i + "").append("<option value=''/><option value='createtest1'>CreateTest1</option><option value='createtest2'>CreateTest2</option>");
            }
            else if(globalObject == 'draft') {
                $("#selectTest" + i + "").append("<option value=''/><option value='drafttest1'>DraftTest1</option><option value='drafttest2'>DraftTest2</option><option value='drafttest3'>DraftTest3</option>");
            }
            else {
               //nothing
            }
        });
    });

    $("#deleteTest").click(function() {
        var test_row = $("#test tr").length - 1;

        if(test_row > 1) {
            $("#testRow" + test_row + "").remove();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
});

function showMatrix() {
    num_rows = $("#objectTable tr").length - 1;
    num_tests = $("#test tr").length;

    for(var x = 0; x < num_rows; x++) {
        myArray[x] = new Array();
        myArray[x] = $("#select" + (x + 1) + "").val();

        for(var z = 0; z < num_tests; z++) {
            myArray[x][z] = firstSelection.item + firstSelection.index;
        }

    }

    alert(myArray);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jwajc/33/)

Comment: Has the error message gone away? Because it doesn't change much for me.

Comment: Moving the function inside the $(document).ready(function() neglects the selected dropdown item of the first row.

Comment: JSFiddle couldn't previously populate my second dropdown, now it can. However, the 2D array still displays only the object values, it doesn't insert the test ones (the second dimension). Any ideas?

Comment: And also, how can I show/hide rows and/or tables based on the 2D array?

Answer (score 0):

Method `showMatrix` can not access local variables of method `firstSelection` like that.

To make a variable in function `showMatrix` visible in function `firstSelection`, you have three choices:

- make it a global,
- make it an object property, or
- pass it as a parameter when calling `firstSelection` from `showMatrix`.

The third option is probably the best options, globals are not recommended to work with and even though project properties are very optimal it's maybe not the best fit for your case.

Just make sure that `firstSelection` returns the variables you need from it and access them within `showMatrix`. You can also make it return an object which holds the values of the variables that you need.

```
function firstSelection(id) {
    var index = id.replace( /\D+/g, '');
    var item = $("#select" + index + "").val();
    // ... some code
    var vars = {index: index, item: item};
    return vars;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am working on the last one, I also think it's the best solution. However, my array is still doing nothing regarding the second dropdown selection...